# Horizontal Gravitational Force

Tags: newtonian-gravity, vectors

So I was writing a lab report for Physics I, where I was describing projectile motion. I had written

> Since gravity on Earth does not have a horizontal force, the object
>   will not lose horizontal velocity (velocity in the x direction).

Then this made me think, is there any gravitational force found in nature that has both vertical *and horizontal* components?

Comment: For practical applications the newtonian format is adequate, considering that it is where the limit of general relativity and special relativity end ( low relative velocities, low gravitational wells). an interesting map : http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/04/110406-new-map-earth-gravity-geoid-goce-esa-nasa-science/ here. With respect to the curvature of the earth this plot shows both horizontal and vertical components.

Comment: If you look at the earth as a whole, the field is not horizontal at all! It's like this: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/PvkJa.jpg
Horizontal/Vertical *completely* depends on the direction of motion which **you** have with respect to the field.

Comment: Due to Earth's centripetal force, would gravity be acting against me (the observer) in the horizontal too? That is to say, if the Earth stopped revolving, would my horizontal movements relative to the earth theoretically be affected at all?

Comment: Tidal forces (caused by gravity) include a horizontal component. In extreme cases, as near a black hole, they can lead to "spaghettification".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it, "vertical" is generally defined as the direction in which things fall - that is, parallel to the local gravitational field. So by that definition of "vertical," no, it is not possible. But if you were to use a different definition of "vertical" and "horizontal," sure, it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Point particles produce gravitational forces only in radial direction. However, for extended objects you have to integrate over all points. This determines the direction of the force. How would you define horizontal and radial for an extended object anyway?